# What are these markings on my sculpting model?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am using the mirror modifier to poly model and sculpt this head. These marks appear on the nose and the big one looks like a mouth :). How can I get rid of them? Adjusting them just makes a seam down the middle. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be the order of the modifiers. Put the mirror modifier befor the subdiv modifier!
Also make sure to check the merge checkbox on the mirror modifier...

Comment: Turn on "Clipping" on the merge modifier as well